# Transit visa for Narita

Tags: visas, japan, canadian-citizens, filipino-citizens

My girlfriend and I are travelling to the Philippines in November of this year 2013. We fly with Air Canada to Narita Tokyo from there we fly with ANA airlines to Manilla. We have a 2:20 minute layover. I have a Canadian passport and she has a passport from the Philippines. When we return, we fly with Jetstar from Manilla to Tokyo where we have a 4:50 minute layover then fly with Air Canada to Toronto. My question is " Do we need transit visa's for Narita? And if we have to leave the terminal to catch our connecting flight in another terminal do we need a visa in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Narita offers [sterile international transfer](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/connect/inter/index.html), so **no**, you do not need transit visas.  Obviously you will need to demonstrate to airline staff when leaving Manila and Toronto that you have connecting flights to take you out of Japan.

Incidentally, as a Canadian you can enter Japan without a prior visa, and your girlfriend would also probably be eligible for a [shore pass](http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/ttp/sg/05-EntryProcedures/MediumIndex/02-Visas/A-Visa.html) of up to 72 hours on arrival.  (Young Philippine women would usually be considered high-risk, since there are so many working in the nightlife industry in Japan illegally, but since you're travelling together and connecting to a Western country, you'd be unlikely to have problems.)  This is unlikely to be worth the hassle if you only have a 5-hour layover though, but next time...

Comment: Ehhh .. IDK, they could go into Narita City.  I should have the last time I had a layover there of similar length.  *If* it's not a big hassle.