# Japan transit visa for a Filipino who has just acquired Canadian citizenship but has no Canadian passport

Tags: visas, transit, japan, filipino-citizens, canadian-citizens

My girlfriend and I want to buy a bargain flight to Thailand from Toronto. We would be saving over $1,000 between the two of us. The return leg stops over at Narita for 11 hr and 50 minutes. There are a lot of great hotels in the $100.00 range we'd like to check into which are a short distance from the airport. I'll have no problem but she is travelling with a Filipino passport. She very recently got her Canadian citizenship but doesn't have a Canadian passport yet. I want to buy the ticket almost immediately because the bargain may disappear. We will be flying next Saturday (Feb 21) so no time for her to get a Visa. We don't want to stay at the terminal for almost 12 hours. Any way we can get into Japan for a very short stay?

A prompt answer would be appreciated due to our time restriction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transit visa for Narita](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/transit-visa-for-narita)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate since OP wishes to enter the country.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you postpone international travel until your girlfriend has a Canadian passport, or she may have *significant* problems returning to the country: most airlines will not accept anything other than a passport as proof of citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

She will have no problem re entering Canada as she also has a permanent residence card. We've travelled overseas before and no problem. But I think that we need to book a full fare flight because she won't be able to enter Japan for 12 hrs. and we don't want to sit at the airport for so long.

Comment: When you acquire citizenship in Canada, they take your permanent residence card the day they grant you citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should book the ticket and apply for a canadian passport and pay for urgent processing. Your passport will cost close to 300 CAD with the additional fee tacked on but it should still be worth it if you are saving that much money on the tickets. If you show the passport office proof of travel (the ticket) and pay the necessary fee, you will be issued the passport in 24h.